# Do we need a crystallography tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This question is brought about by this post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235573/determine-the-coordinates-of-octahedral-and-tetrahedral-sites-relative-to-th

Reasons *for* [crystallography]:

- There is a large amount of current mathematics devoted to crystallography ranging from inverse scattering, X-ray/Radon transforms, and especially the study of the [phase problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_problem)
- The geometry of unit cells of crystal lattices is mathematical (the tiling problem in 3D).
- It is a somewhat special field at the intersection of group theory, linear algebra, Fourier analysis, and analytic geometry (perhaps more?)

Reasons *against* [crystallography]:

- It is a somewhat specialised field, and we may not get much call for questions of that sort here.
- Questions that would fall under this tag could in principal be tagged as a combination of other tags. (The question linked above could perhaps have the [tiling] and [analytic-geometry] tags added.)

---

Thoughts?

Comment: No. We don't need it.

Comment: Maybe not yet; geometry would cover the question in, uhurm, question for the time being (and didn't we once have a [tag:lattices] tag?). If we are suddenly awash in crystallographic questions, then I suppose we can reconsider...

Comment: *Special* in the sense of *specialized*, I presume.

Comment: @J.M. That tag was split into [tag:lattice-orders] and [tag:integer-lattices]. 
See [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/3187#3187) and [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/tagging-lattices)

Comment: @did: yes. I edited to reflect that.

Comment: @J.M.: as Martin indicated, the lattices tag was split. And unfortunately neither of them works well for this context. (I guess if we stretch it a bit, integer-lattices can be okay, but it is not ideal.)